# How to find the n-largest edge weights in a network matrix (networkx)?

Tags: python, matrix, scipy, heap, networkx

I have the following code that I attempt to use to generate a network matrix.  With this matrix, I would like to find the 20 highest-weighted edges that ARE NOT on the diagnal (*i.e.* `i!=j` in the matrix).  I also would like to get the names of the nodes (in pairs) composed of these edges.

```
import heapq
def mapper_network(self, _, info):
    G = nx.Graph()  #create a graph
    for i in range(len(info)):   
        edge_from = info[0]  # edge from
        edge_to = info[1]    # edge to
        weight = info[2]     # edge weight
        G.add_edge(edge_from, edge_to, weight=weight) #insert the edge to the graph
    A = nx.adjacency_matrix(G)  # create an adjacency matrix
    A_square = A * A  # find the product of the matrix
    print heapq.nlargest(20, A_square) # to print out the 20 highest weighted edges
```

With this code, however, I failed to generate the 20 most weighted edges. I obtain `raise ValueError("The truth value of an array with more than one "
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all().`

Instead, with this

```
    print heapq.nlargest(20, range(len(A_square)), A_square.take)
```

It gives me:

```
    raise TypeError("sparse matrix length is ambiguous; use getnnz()"
    TypeError: sparse matrix length is ambiguous; use getnnz() or shape[0]
```

With

```
    def mapper_network(self, _, info):
    G = nx.Graph()
    for i in range(len(info)):
        edge_from = info[0]
        edge_to = info[1]
        weight = info[2]
        G.add_edge(edge_from, edge_to, weight=weight)
    A = nx.adjacency_matrix(G)
    A_square = A * A #can print (A_square.todense())
    weight = nx.get_edge_attributes(A_square, weight)
    edges = A_square.edges(data = True)
    s = sorted(G.edges(data=True), key=lambda (source, target, data): data['weight'])
    print s
```

I received

```
  File         "/tmp/MRQ7_trevor.vagrant.20160814.040827.770006/job_local_dir/1/mapper/0/mrjob.tar.gz/mrjob/job.py", line 433, in run
mr_job.execute()
 File "/tmp/MRQ7_trevor.vagrant.20160814.040827.770006/job_local_dir/1/mapper/0/mrjob.tar.gz/mrjob/job.py", line 442, in execute
self.run_mapper(self.options.step_num)
 File "/tmp/MRQ7_trevor.vagrant.20160814.040827.770006/job_local_dir/1/mapper/0/mrjob.tar.gz/mrjob/job.py", line 507, in run_mapper
for out_key, out_value in mapper(key, value) or ():
File "MRQ7_trevor.py", line 90, in mapper_network
weight = nx.get_edge_attributes(A_square, weight)
File "/home/vagrant/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/networkx/classes/function.py", line 428, in get_edge_attributes
if G.is_multigraph():
File "/home/vagrant/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/sparse/base.py", line 499, in __getattr__
raise AttributeError(attr + " not found")
```

AttributeError: is_multigraph not found

Could someone help me solve this question? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

The issue with this line:

```
heapq.nlargest(20, A_square)
```

Is that `nlargest` does not expect an iterable of iterables, but an interable of numbers.

So you could do this instead:

```
heapq.nlargest(20, itertools.chain.from_iterable(A_square))
```

[`itertools.chain.iterables`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) takes an iterable of iterables, and creates a new iterable with the content of all the inner iterables.

---

However, that won't entierly solve your initial problem, for two reasons:

1. Why do you take the square of the adjacency matrix? Doing so would only give you the highest weighted sum of paths of length 2 in the graph, which is quite different from what you want. Just use the adjacency matrix instead.
2. Nowhere in your code you remove the diagonal. You could do it like this: `for n in G.number_of_nodes():  A[n][n] = 0`

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. I took the square of the adjacency matrix because I wanted to know which nodes are 'most connected with a shared nodes'. For instance, A-B, A-C, but !B-C. B and C are connected via A. I hope to know which pair of nodes are the most connected in this way. I tried  for n in G.number_of_edges():  A[n][n] = 0 but it shows no attribute number_of edges. I also hope to know the node names (edges) (i.e. A-C) but don't know how to do it with sparse csv matrix. Thank you!

Comment: Sorry, I meant `number_of_nodes()` (which is the size of the matrix)